# How to detect the mouse and keyboard on a USB KVM extender with a Powershell script?

Tags: powershell, keyboard, mouse, powershell-remoting

I'm checking that the mouse and keyboard are properly connected to a remote PC, with a PS script. The catch is that the mouse and keyboard are connected through a USB KVM extender to the remote PC.

What I thought would work is simply looking for the connected mice and keyboards by using the following commands:

```
Get-CimInstance win32_POINTINGDEVICE 
Get-CimInstance win32_KEYBOARD
```

However, I noticed that these commands return me a positive result EVEN when the mouse and keyboard are disconnected, just because the KVM extender is connected. So essentially what it does is simply check that the KVM is connected, which is not what I'm looking for. It detects the KVM as a "Pointing Device" and "Keyboard" on its own (both commands return me the KVM device ID).

How can I circumvent this problem?

I thought of checking that the mouse is connected by checking if it's active with a script (checking if it moves), but this is not what I want because the idea is to automate the checking remotely (there is no operator in front of said PC to move the mouse).

Comment: Which KVM? I have a very cheap KVM that is basically a usb hub and an HDMI hub attached to the same switch, but I have used KVMs that have drivers and subprocess mouse and keyboard input. We won't be able to answer your question without knowing the specifics of what device you're trying to use.

Comment: You can't do this, precisely because the KVM extender emulates a USB keyboard and mouse regardless of the presence of the physical input devices.